# Is there a way to open multiple Java projects in one window in VScode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Can I open multiple tabs of java files from different projects in one window in VScode?
Also, what is the best way to manage Java projects in VScode, suggestions, if any?

Answer (score 1):

Open in new Tab Solution: Open the command palette by: Cmd + Shift + K. Open settings file by: Preferences: Open Settings (JSON) Under user setting, enable Tabs by: "workbench. You can switch between views using ctrl + 1 ( ⌘ + 1 ), ctrl + 2 ( ⌘ + 2 ), and so on. Alternatively, you can switch between tabs (and, by extension, between views) using ctrl + page up / page down ( ⌘ + page up / page down ).

or

VS Code now has the concept of a 'workspace' which lets you add several 'root' folders to VS Code in the same window. For instance, when working on a project in one folder that utilizes shared code held in a different folder, you can now open both the project folder and the shared folder in the same window. To do this you use the Add folder to Workspace... command. VS Code then saves this configuration in a new file with a .code-workspace extension. If you double-click that file, VS Code will re-open with both folders present.

for more information, visit: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/codebasics